# Stuck in a fun exercise: I want to test the randomness of the random library in Python

Tags: python, random, statistics

I want to preface this by saying I am a newbie. I was trying to entertain myself and keep myself interested in coding, and I came with an idea. I want to test the randomness of the random library. I know it is not truly random, thus the interest in the question.

Basically what I want to do is to generate 10,000 random numbers and assign them to a string. Then I want to find out the mean, median and standard deviation of this list and attach them each to their own lists. Then I want to populate those strings with another 9,999 other means, medians and standard deviations from another 9,999 randomly generated lists. Then I want to finally do the mean, median and standard deviation of each of these 3 lists (of mean, median and standard deviation). I hope it makes sense.

With the help of the internet, I found this partial solution:

I have already imported random as rd, math as math and statistics as st.

```
numbers = [rd.randint(1,10000) for i in range(10000)]
```

to generate 10,000 random numbers (for each element in the range(10000) I want a different random number)

```
print(st.mean(numbers))
print(st.median(numbers))
print(st.stdev(numbers))
```

now I printed the mean, median and stdev of the string of numbers that I have generated before'

Now I want to do this 9,999 times more, putting the 9,999 collections of means, medians and stdevs in their own lists.

It feels like I would need to use a for loop, but I don't know how to really think about it in practical terms. Going back to theory is not super useful, as then I feel like doing a practical and meaningful example and then I get back here again. I think seeing it in action with an example I would understand and care about would put it into perspective better.

I know that testing the randomness can probably be done quicker and more efficient than what I thought about here (and I would love to learn it eventually), but can you help me putting into code what was in my mind? Does it even make sense coding-wise?

Comment: why would you want to put each into strings ? wouldn't it be better to work with arrays ? or even a dataframe?

Comment: Don't know yet how to use arrays. Nor do I know how to properly and confidently print those numbers into a dataframe and then pull it from there. That's the best I could come up with, considering my limited knowledge of coding. As I said, I am sure there is a better way to do this more efficiently, but I am also sure that if someone shows it to me in that efficient way, I probably wouldn't grasp it and grasp the concepts used as well as if someone showed me how it could be done the way I imagined it.

Comment: I also think that you may be mixing up the terms "variable" and "strings".  But I might be wrong.

Comment: True. I think I corrected it. English is not my native language and intuitively strings is more like the string of numbers in a list than a list.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will definitely do that. What I did is tried to make a small project and got stuck and asked if anyone has any suggestions whether what I was trying to do is feasible and how they would go about doing that.

Comment: I feel that after going through a lot of tutorials, they either focus too much on the theory, or they make some simple examples that don't stick to me as they have little meaning. I am more comfortable going into a task or challenge and then trying to see if anyone is willing to show me how it's done from there, as I don't come from a technical background and it is hard for me to conceptualize and transform the theoretical/abstract into something concrete.

Comment: I didn't know that SO wasn't like a forum or asking very basic questions is discouraged. I will take time to go through the tutorials again and return, hopefully with a more advanced understanding of what I am trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that there’s ***way*** more to testing random numbers than just checking means, medians, and standard deviations. If you want to calculate those three statistics as a programming exercise that’s fine, but don’t kid yourself that you’ve tested the random number generator in a meaningful way.

Comment: Of course, there are a lot of descriptors, I just wanted to see if I could actually find a way to just code these three. Hence the "fun excercise" part of the title of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I can certainly help with that. Here is some code that can accomplish that:

```
import random as rd
import statistics as st

length = 10000

meanlist = [st.mean(values) for values in [[rd.randint(1,10000) for i in range(10000)] for x in range(0, 10000)]]
medianlist = [st.median(values) for values in [[rd.randint(1,10000) for i in range(10000)] for x in range(0, 10000)]]
stdevlist = [st.stdev(values) for values in [[rd.randint(1,10000) for i in range(10000)] for x in range(0, 10000)]]
```

Let me explain how the code works. Each list uses 3 nested list comprehensions, each for a different purpose. The outer one takes the mean of each set of 10000 trials, the middle one repeats all 10000 trials in each set, and the inner one is what you wrote in your question; the code for each trial.

Comment: Wow, thank you! There is quite a lot to unpack for me here. I will run it and see what happens when I get the chance. I would give you a thumbs up if I could (I am so far limited). One question that I have right off the bat is why you  defined the length variable, since I don't see it used in the code.

Comment: You used 10,000, but I think it's worth generalising this to different numbers. :)

Comment: So i guess I could replace every instance of 10,000 with length within the code and then replace only the value assigned to the length above in order to instantly change the code to output different list lengths?

Comment: Yup! It's just good coding practice to take certain constants and make them variables when making problems, so others can easily use your code without having to replace every instance of your constant with their new constant.